# How to initiate a Microsoft Teams call(preferably video) from an external application?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to build an application which can initiate Teams video call to certain users.

The application will be running on a stand alone machine(like a kiosk) and upon a certain event, the application should be able to start a teams call to one more more users.

What is the best way to do this ? Following are my questions -

1. Does the Teams need to run under a resource account on that machine ?
2. Does this need the help of a teams bot? If it needs a bot, does it need to have a teams account associated with it ?
3. Do I need Microsoft graph to make the call ? Does graph support video call ?
4. Can the Microsoft Teams Rooms be used in any way to achieve this ?

I have been reading different documents which seem to offer some aspect of what I want, but not sure what is the best way here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use Graph API to create call using external application. check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)?

Comment: Are you still facing any issue? could you please conform/

Comment: could you please update?

Answer (score 1):

We can initiate a Microsoft Teams call from an external application, We can [create a call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using an Graph API using an external application. When a call is created need to mention the requestedModalities where audio/video/videoBasedScreenSharing can be define for a call. please check the properties in [Call resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/call?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) .